# Embed view as title inside SwiftUI navigation bar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to embed a switch into the navigation view like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg8Hu.png)

In UIKit, this is very easy: add the switch right after the navigation bar loads by doing `self.navigationItem.titleView = controllSwitch` However, with SwiftUI I can't do that.

Here's my swiftui code:

```swift
struct NotesDetail: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(note.color)
            .opacity(0.25)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Hello World")
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
struct NotesDetail: View {

    @State private var toggleNow = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Toggle")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    HStack {
                        Toggle(isOn: $toggleNow) {
                            Text("")
                        }

                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, UIScreen.screenWidth/2.5)
            )
        }
    }
}

extension UIScreen{
    static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
}
```

[image]